# Define a UI element like the ones in jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, widget

In jQuery UI, widgets are created like this:

```
$("#selector").accordion({ //options });
```

How would I go about creating my own widget that would be created like this?  Mainly, I need to know how to define a function that can be called on a DOM element (I'm a javascript newbie and the jQuery UI code isn't so readable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn how to create a [jQuery plug-in](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). It's pretty great for organizing your code and makes it easier to reuse functionality.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of documentation I was looking for.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

worlds smallest jQuery plugin! [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGp5E/6/)

```
$.fn.myFunc = function(){
    alert($(this).length)
};
$('div').myFunc();
```

​

Comment: +1 for compactness. It's still good to point out that this is not considered as a best practice. Namespacing, defaults etc. should also be handled correctly. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: Very straight to the point.  It really gave me a feel of how things are declared.